# Firestore security rules - if exists statement

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I was trying to implement the security rules for my Firestore project. This statement here isn't working, can anyone tell me why? I am clueless at this point.

What I am trying to achieve: a user may only read the userlist if that user is on the userlist.

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {  

     match /groups/{group}/userlist/{document=**}{
        allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/groups/$(group)/userlist/$(request.auth.uid));

     //for troubleshooting: the general rule below works fine and access is granted 
     //allow read :if request.auth.uid != null;

    }
  }
```

Here is a code example from my app where the access with said statement is not granted. As I said in the commented lines within the "rules" code: I get the results when I set the rules to a more general access-condition.

The following code is from the onBind within an adapter. I added a line that prints the uid just to be sure.

```
System.out.println("UserId: "+ mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

db.collection("groups").document(model.getGroupId()).collection("userlist").get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {

                int members = queryDocumentSnapshots.size();
                holder.mPreviewText.setText("Number of Members: " + members);
            }
        });
```

```
I/System.out: UserId: iWBdGRNmJCOEtXWKefeD2T7cH1l2
I/System.out: UserId: iWBdGRNmJCOEtXWKefeD2T7cH1l2
I/System.out: UserId: iWBdGRNmJCOEtXWKefeD2T7cH1l2
I/System.out: 1
I/System.out: UserId: iWBdGRNmJCOEtXWKefeD2T7cH1l2
W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(groups/uaRV4n21PWov5p6VPlYH/userlist order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
I/System.out: UserId: iWBdGRNmJCOEtXWKefeD2T7cH1l2
I/System.out: UserId: iWBdGRNmJCOEtXWKefeD2T7cH1l2
W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(groups/tqsFIMhaMdZUfx6M3Guz/userlist order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
I/System.out: UserId: iWBdGRNmJCOEtXWKefeD2T7cH1l2
I/System.out: UserId: iWBdGRNmJCOEtXWKefeD2T7cH1l2
W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(groups/tm09NSiqZ5rDaBZzH52g/userlist order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(groups/iye5A0JaltId8xYeQLie/userlist order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(groups/cnj4BOMHY0LlXb7KJsW0/userlist order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(groups/UGmozZfEOKXX1sajT1NW/userlist order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(groups/S4lJIyAMfDtQUTS08PWa/userlist order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(groups/uaRV4n21PWov5p6VPlYH/userlist order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query(groups/tqsFIMhaMdZUfx6M3Guz/userlist order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

I read all the documentation and that's what I think the code should look like but doesn't work, the users who are on the list don't get read permission.

```
Query(target=Query(groups/uaRV4n21PWov5p6VPlYH/userlist order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=PERMISSION_DENIED, description=Missing or insufficient permissions., cause=null}
```

[image: example #1]

Comment: "This statement here isn't working" Can you edit your question to show the minimal, complete code that you run that isn't working against these rules? And given that you're checking for the existence of another document, it'd also be helpful to see a screenshot of the document that you're checking for.

Comment: Not sure what you want to see the screenshot of. Document within console?

Comment: We can't see for sure that 1) the user is signed in with a UID and 2) a document with the UID exists in the correct collection. Without being able to verify these facts, we can't be of much help, since these are the very things your rules are trying to validate.

Comment: Ok but the code itself is alright? I am asking specifically if that code is correct for the purpose iam describing because iam not familiar with firebase security rules. However I don't need help to check if documents exist in my db... And user is signed in with uid as "allow read :if request.auth.uid != null" works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the additional code. That code looks fine at first glance, so all we can say at that point is that indeed `if exists(/databases/$(database)/groups/$(group)/userlist/$(request.auth.uid))` seems to be failing. You'll want to check of the document really exists in the console. To allow us to help you on that double check, post a relevant screenshot in your question.

Comment: I added a screenshot and the corresponding denial. I really can't see where I go wrong with these rules. One thing: is it maybe because of the usage within an adapter? Maybe its to many reads within one second or anything? I use the FirebaseRecyclerAdapter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I finally found my mistake. Sorry for bothering you guys. I was missing "/documents/" in the if-exists-clause.

Correct way:

```
match /databases/{database}/documents {  

     match /groups/{group}/userlist/{document=**}{
        allow read: if exists(/databases/$(database)/documents/groups/$(group)/userlist/$(request.auth.uid));

    }
  }
```

Now it works and everything makes perfect sense again.